# How do you take down a Juggernaut?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In my time of playing the multiplayer, I've noticed the Juggernaut kill streak makes someone nearly invincible, especially if two people do it at the same time. Now my question is what is the best way to take these people down? Just keep shooting? Are there any particularly good techniques to kill them quickly? (or at least keep them from killing your entire team twice)

Comment: They indeed are practically invincible. I managed to survive a Precision Strike right on top of my head on Hard Core. Came very close to death though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the very best way to take down a juggernaut. Use a tactical knife! With 4 knifes in a row, their dead. If your teammates (and flashbangs) can keep him from turning around on you, it's extremely quick to kill them.

Answer (score 13):

Even with Juggernaut players are still very vulnerable to headshots (due to the damage multiplier).  Most headshots 'overkill' a player so you never really realize how much more damage they actually do.

To deal with a juggernaut: crouch behind a box, wait for them to walk by and stick a semtex to them, knife them, or (the most reliable) repeatedly shoot them in the head.

Comment: You will have to knife a juggernaut multiple times to kill him.

Answer (score 7):

Sustained high damage is the key.

Juggernauts heal fairly quickly, so you have to keep up the damage.

Explosives help a lot, but the main thing to do is to make sure they're never getting a chance to heal up. Do this by keeping yourself alive to continuously fire at them, or fire at them with a team mate.

Answer (score 5):

I kill them instantly using a `Predator Missile` kill streak. Obviously you have to wait until the juggernaut is outside before using this though.

Also a light machine can kill them in one round, and you can run circles around them to avoid getting shot.

Answer (score 4):

Beware that clever juggernauts use their Riot Shield very effectively, and they stay next to other teammates as a *tank* to draw fire and attention.

Keep your distance.
If you are caught in the open and are alone, try throwing a 9-bang into his face, turn back and run.

Team work and focus-fire are very important, do not let him fight back:  9-bang, fire, 9-bang, reload, 9-bang, and so on. He will use his Riot shield a lot, so try to throw nades behind, or surround him.

Plant explosives and lure him into your trap. They stumble on explosive impact, which should give you precious seconds to unload onto him.

Answer (score 4):

Use a stinger to lock him and take him down. A stinger missile is a one-shot-kill headshot to a Juggernaught.

Comment: Stinger is a lock-on only anti-air missle. How do you use that against a juggernaut?

Comment: Actually you can lock onto juggernauts and assault drones. See this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBwEYH6yuW0

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using akimbo FMG9's at point blank range kills juggernauts very effectively. It should be able to kill one in one pair of rounds.

Answer (score 1):

Hide behind a corner and put down a Claymore (Stand close if you need to shoot or knife). You will probably get damaged but you took out the Juggernaught. (This also works with a Bouncing Betty)

Answer (score 1):

How about making sure he never gets his juggernaut in the first place?
The juggernaut airdrop looks different to a normal airdrop, (it's a C-130 Hercules(the juggernaut one)) and it will always fly towards the person that dropped the marker. Take him out and hav the juggernaut all to yourself. 
I have called in a recon juggernaut 3 times and each one I have been killed before I can use it. But once my teammate got it. 
As for actually taking it down, teamwork is crucial. Change to an Lmg class or a launcher class and then just blow them away. Juggernaut are very slow. And the recon juggernaut doesn't have an M60. You can just run away from them and get to a good spot and launch a missile at their face.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

if you want to kill juggernaut you need 2 players to be able to kill. all the players must first buy submashinegun, which costs $ 2,000. Upgrade him the whole time until the last level. as the juggernaut is coming, the best headshot maker still on the main shoot, the other on the body, you should also shoot together!

Answer (score 0):

Shoot them in the back with a SMAW or with an ACR 6.8 M320 (acr with a grenade launcher) use both bullets and grenades

Answer (score 0):

Get a predator missile and jam down on his head. Or team up with your teammates and go for the head. Or use a light machine gun with extended mags and scavenger pro.

Answer (score 0):

One of my best techniques is use Model 1887, then melee once a juggernaut crouches down in pain. That's what I do. Others prefer a flash grenade to blind the naut, to keep shooting again and again, camp in spot and attack from behind, etc. 
Hmm... If only they had Brown Besses... I could fix a couple of Russians with bayonets...

Answer (score 0):

Hit the bitch with SMAW right in the face after that just a few bullet with the LMG and it's over just make sure to use flash bangs before doing any thing and that's that

Answer (score 0):

There are several effective ways to take down Juggernauts. Here are some:

1. **Using a SMAW:** This is my favorite approach. *Flash the Juggernaut* (Juggernauts are slow, they can't run for cover on being flashed). *Then shoot them with a SMAW*. Usually one SMAW hit is does the job. If not, take cover and keep shooting it, or dealing some kind of damage immediately. This is the only approach you can use in any condition, without needing support from team members.
2. **Throwing knife:** Throwing knife is very effective against the Juggernaut. 4 - 5 throwing knife shots kills it. *Take help from teammates to keep the Juggernaut blinded* (flashbangs, stun grenades etc.).
3. **Predator missile:** Predator missile is super effective against Juggernauts. However, it requires that you have a predator missile available and that the Juggernaut is in open. So not always an option.
4. **Team attack:** 3-4 people raining fire on the Juggernauts destroys it quickly. *Aim for the head!* Juggernauts are very weak in the head :)

***Key idea behind taking down a Juggernaut is to deal a high amount of damage rapidly***. Juggernauts quickly recover health, you don't want to give that chance to it.

Explosives like grenades or semtex are pretty useless against a Juggernaut if you are attacking it alone, use them just before you open fire or when team members are attacking it to throw the juggernaut off-balance.

Team attack is the most common, immediate response to Juggernauts. ***Weapons like MP7 with rapid fire, MP9 akimbo, ACR and grenade launcher attachments with assault rifles are most favorable in these cases.*** *Also, do try using XM-25 or shooting it in the head with a non bolt action sniper rifle in such attacks.*

So there you go, a manual for taking down Juggernauts. Now go show them who is the tough guy :)