# Does the Juggernaut's health increase progressively in Survival?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When playing Survival it quickly becomes apparent that the health of the standard enemy soldier goes up either per round or per-so-many rounds.

Does this also apply for the Juggernauts? I usually kill them with C4 and at first I thought it always takes 7 C4 stacked to kill the first Jugg that I get.

However I've sometimes killed a Jugg with as little as 5 C4 packs, so now I'm aware that how close they are to the packs themselves when they blow is a major factor in how much damage they take. Unfortunately this has also completely derailed any idea as to how much health they have and if it increases or not as you continue to progress through the survival waves.

Comment: I don't have a source for this, but from my experience, their health is pretty constant.  The game ups the difficulty by spawning more of them, or giving you waves that have both juggernauts and other enemies, and not by increasing their health.

Comment: I don't believe so - I think the health stays constant. C4 is not a very efficient way to kill them, however. See this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34657/how-do-you-take-down-a-juggernaut for a discussion on good ways to kill the juggernauts. My personal favorite is a predator missile directly on them

Comment: @Sumner- you are aware that I'm referring to survival Juggs right? Multiplayer Juggs are a completely different demon.

Comment: I think all enemy health are same . but they use different Amount of shield!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALL enemies get tougher as the game progresses to higher waves.

This video shows what is possibly the highest legitimate waves that anyone has gotten to (wave 153):

By wave 120+, Juggernauts can eat 5 Predator Missiles directly to the head and survive, compared to a single missile taking out a wave 6 Juggernaut.
Looks like even the regular FAD-armed enemies need 30+ bullets from an LMG to kill.
Fortunately despite their increased toughness, flashbangs still stun them as long as before.

By that time, the vastly higher total damage from the Airstrike marker barrage makes it much more useful than Predator Missiles.

Answer (score 3):

No, they stay the same all the way through, just spawn more and more of them to increase difficulty. http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernaut_%28enemy%29 it only states that there are different type's of Juggernaut's.

Comment: quoted from that website's article-- 'there is an "Armored Juggernaut" that appears in the boss waves. These Juggernauts heavily resemble the ones from Modern Warfare 2 and take much longer to kill.'-- what are these boss waves?

Comment: I believe it's wave 30 or so.

Answer (score -1):

As you get to higher waves, the Juggernauts will have more health.

Comment: Hey andrew, welcome to the site. This contradicts the other answers  that have been posted; do you have any proof that they have more health later on?

Answer (score -1):

This is my wave 126 in survival mode :-) I have some to upload as well

Comment: We avoid link/video only answers, in case the source goes down. Can you summarize what in the video addresses the question?

Comment: Does watching your wave 126 answer the question?